# How do I get straight corners in QLineEdit?

Tags: qt

By default on the operating system that I use, I get QLineEdits with rounded corners, what do I need to write in style sheets to make them straight? `QLineEdit { border-radius: 0px; }` didn't work;

Answer (score 0):

You can select a diferent style for your Qt Gui as a whole like Plastique:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/gallery-plastique.html

Here is the gallery for 4.8.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/gallery.html

If `border-radius: 0;`  Doesn't work for you , then your style is not customizable.